# Prove that $f_1, \ldots, f_n$ are vector Linearly Independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $f_1, f_2,  \ldots, f_n \in C^{n-1}(\mathbb{R})$. Prove that if there is $v$ such that the matrix

$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}{f_{1}(v)} & {\ldots} & {f_{n}(v)} \\ {f_{1}^{\prime}(v)} & {\cdots} & {f_{n}^{\prime}(v)} \\ {\vdots} & {\ddots} & {\vdots} \\ {f_{1}^{(n-1)}(v)} & {\dots} & {f_{n}^{(n-1)}(v)}\end{array}\right)
$$

is invertible, then, $f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_n$ are linearly independent.

I can't do it.

Comment: Assume that $\sum_{k=1}^na_kf_k(x)$ is the zero function. Then rake derivatives of this equation, one, twice, ..., $n-1$ times to get $n$ equations. Plug in $x=v$. Solve for the coefficients $a_k$. Since that is the matrix of the system that you got, that means that the system has only the solution $a_1=...=a_n=0$.

Comment: Show the contrapositive. Suppose that $f_1, f_2,\dots,f_n$ are linearly dependent. Keep differentiating the equation expressing the linear dependence to find a linear dependence between columns of the above matrix. Since the columns are linearly dependent, the matrix can't be invertible. This matrix is called the Wronskian.

Comment: @JaneDoé thanks for the comments. I didn´t know about the name of matrix "the Wronskian". I will search about now.

Comment: @logarithm thanks too much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} c_kf_k=0$ then $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} c_kf_k^{(j)}=0$ for $0 \leq j \leq n-1$. In particular $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} c_kf_k^{(j)}(v)=0$ for $0 \leq j \leq n-1$. Since the matrix of this linear system is invertible we get $c_i=0$ for all $i$.